# Overriding method in eclipse via source-Override/implement method paste method call for me.Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding

I hope this is not a duplicate, because I didn't find answer an for this. Only something refering to c++ destructors, but I know nothing about that. Anyway I'm used to override my methods on my own bud to speed up process I now go trought eclipse  source-override/implement methods and I don't understand why **eclipse automaticly paste**

```
 super.method(event);
```

**into my code,Why eclipse does this for me?** Does it actually do anything?I already call that method anyway,why it have to be there twice i dont understand.
example of what i mean:

```
    someJlabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.mouseEntered(e); // <-- 
        }

    });
```

I already know that if i don't have it there everything works ok and if I do also.So if anyone can explain this to me i would be  really happy its a small thing bud I want to know whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls the method with the same name from the super/parent class. Generally it is up to you if you want to include that call to the parent class or not. Eclipse is just suggesting it. If that method in the parent class does nothing (e.g. has an empty body), then purely practically viewed it does not matter if you add this call or not in the derived/child class. But if the method in the parent class does something useful, then it is sometimes a good idea to include that call, as you would get the parent class behavior too. That's why Eclipse is suggesting you do it.

Comment: This pretty much explain it all.Thank you, i think it will be good practice for me to keep it there side by side with my code then.

Answer (score 2):

`super.mouseEntered(e);` is call to method `mouseEntered()` as it's defined in **the parent class** of MouseAdapter. So it's not the same method called twice.

While overriding methods you often call the super method (such as you call super in constructor) and then you can do some additional actions. If you leave just super.method() there, then it's going to behave as if you didn't override it at all.